# Fruit leather sticking to parchment paper

Tags: oven, food-preservation, fruit, parchment, fruit-leather

Having some trouble making strawberry fruit leather for the first time. I'm pureeing frozen strawberries in orange juice then spreading the puree on parchment paper that I put on a pan. I then put it in the oven at 175 degrees. I've tried leaving it for 1 hour, 2 hours, or 3 hours. But it always ends up being really thin and sticking to the parchment paper to the point that it's impossible to separate from the paper. What should I change in my steps above?

Comment: Are you positive you used parchment paper? A common mistake is using wax paper instead of parchment paper. Wax paper isn't oven-safe, and will melt the wax which can stick to whatever you put on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a little cooking spray (pan release) on the pan, or, another option would be to use a silicone mat.

Answer (score 0):

Stuck parchment paper fix: wet the back with a paper towel, really saturate the parchment paper. Then peal off. Scrape off any remainder. Whew! fruit leather saved!